# Angular ngBlur "sender"?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Newbie question.

My **Input** element has a **ng-blur** directive set which fires nicely. The function it calls on the **$scope** is generic. How do I know what **Input element X** was the sender when I am in the **$scope.MyBlur()** function?

The "this" keyword is the $scope it seems in the function.

Comment: what does the markup look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<input ng-blur='blurFunc($event)'/>
```

Then use `$event.target` in your controller.

http://jsfiddle.net/emmaguo/butek3ro/